# Incorrectly applied brightness/contrast modifier in my scene

Tags: modifiers, video-sequence-editor

I can't figure out how to reset the brightness of the image in my scene. In my first scene the images are nice white but in my second scene it is a bit darker. I did play around with the `brightness/contrast modifier` (negative brightness) with some parts of the `video-sequencer` which is probably causing this frustrating bug now to my newly imported images. Any ideas of a workaround?

As a workaround I tried removing all modifiers through script as well to no avail

```
for i in bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.sequences_all:
    i.modifiers.clear()
```

It removes all modifiers but the bug remains. Any other workarounds like how do i clear the cache?

[image]

As you can see this image does not have any modifiers applied. Please see the simplified attached file with only 1 scene and 1 image here: https://blend-exchange.com/b/QRKOrDgs . Try importing another white image, it will have the same brightness problem.

[image]

**WORKAROUND**: creating a new scene won't work either, it will retain the bug. Good thing i had 1 scene that was working so i made a `full copy` of the scene then copied the stuff from the defective scene and then deleted it. Now i can import normal white images again.

Comment: For some reason, your file appears to be blank at my end, even though you've packed the data... Can you consider repacking the video or checking if the video appears on your own link?

Comment: its ok,  you don't need it. just import a white image and you will see the bug, it's not perfectly 0xFFFFFF white

Comment: What about increasing the exposure/setting the colour mode to high contrast to fix the dim?

Comment: so were you able to see the problem when importing a white image? i cant because it would also affect the images that work properly. anyway i reported this as a bug https://developer.blender.org/T98585

Comment: Yeah, I could see the problem. It's confusing if it's a bug though, which version of blender are you using? I'm using blender 3.1.2

Comment: yes im also on blender 3.1.2. i think it still is reproducible on the latest 3.2 and 3.3 versions. i tried removing all modifiers via script `for i in bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.sequences_all:
    i.modifiers.clear()` but also futile. maybe there is a way to clear the cache or something?

Comment: Other than copy pasting/moving it into a new file, I'm not sure.

Comment: just wanted to give an update. see the answer for the real solution i just discovered

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it looks like a bug. i already reported the bug here https://developer.blender.org/T98585.

**UPDATE**: something caused the **Color Management**'s `View Transform` to change from `Standard` to `Filmic`. Changing it back to `Standard` fixed the problem.

Comment: Amazing, it was so simple! And all the time I thought that _Filmic_ was the default best for everything and that standard doesn't look realistic.

Comment: yeah! what a coincidence i was tinkering with brightness so i thought that it was related. something must have caused it to change to filmic because i NEVER ever touch those. they claimed i must have accidentally change it to filmic but thats impossible because i never uncollapse the color management tab so theres no way i have changed it.